# A city has an average 2.3 children per family. Randomly chosen child has avg of 1.6 siblings. Determine variance of number of children

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

A city has an average 2.3 children per family. Randomly chosen child has avg of 1.6 siblings. Determine variance of number of children in a random family

I'm assuming it's the 2 Poisson's multiplied together then get their expectation, which is

$$2.3^ke^{-2.3}/k!$$
$$1.6^ke^{-1.6}/k!$$

E[X*Y]=E[X]*E[Y]=2.5*1.6
But this seems off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no Poisson distribution here.

Hint: If $X$ is the number of children in a family in this population, you're told
$\mathbb E[X] = 2.3$, and $\mathbb E[X (X-1)]/\mathbb E[X] = 1.6$.  Find
$\mathbb E[X^2]$ and then the variance.

Comment: +1 If $\mathbb E[Y]$ is the average number of family children per child so $2.6$ here and $\mathbb E[X]$ is the average number of family children per family so $2.3$ here, then $\mathbb E[X^2] = \mathbb E[X] \mathbb E[Y]$.  Is there an alternative reason to your argument of saying  $\mathbb E[Y] = \frac{\mathbb E[X^2]}{\mathbb E[X]}$?

Comment: There are two different probability distributions here: one for a random family, and one for a random child.  When counting by family, each family has the same weight.  But when counting by child, a family with $x$ children has $x$ times as much weight as a family with $1$ child.